# Is there a way to use AutoMapper's ProjectTo with Entity Framework Core's FromSql?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

When I call this method of mine

```
public async Task<List<TEntityDto>> ListFromSqlAsync(FormattableString sql, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var res = await
        Repo.Context.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(sql)
            .IgnoreQueryFilters()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ProjectTo<TEntityDto>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync(ct);
    return res;
}
```

Like this:

```
await _queryService.ListFromSqlAsync( $"EXEC chronos.RecentStaffCompanies", cancellationToken);
```

I get

> FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a
> query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the
> method to perform the composition on the client side.

If I comment out the ProjectTo and map in memory after ToList using Mapper.Map it works

The procedure returns the full object that is DbSet

I hate to have to read the full object to memory to return a subset of the fields. Any way to make this work (DB is SQL Server)

The sproc is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE chronos.RecentStaffCompanies
AS
    select *
    from chronos.Company c
    where c.CompanyTypeId in (0, 4) 
    and c.IsDeleted=0
    and exists(
        select * from chronos.staff s
        join chronos.office o on o.id = s.OfficeId
        where o.CompanyId = c.Id
        and s.IsDeleted=0
        and exists (
            select * from chronos.Journal j where j.StaffId = s.Id and j.IsDeleted = 0 and j.Date >= DATEADD( YEAR, -1, GETUTCDATE() )
        )
    )
    order by c.Name
GO
```

Comment: do you have a `";"` on the real sql when calling `await _queryService.ListFromSqlAsync( $"EXEC chronos.RecentStaffCompanies", cancellationToken);` ?

Comment: You can't do `SELECT` over a stored-procedure result (i.e. non-composable), that's basically what `ProjectTo` tries to do.

Comment: Agree with Gert, and I also do not see the reason of creating such stored procedure. It can be covered by LINQ with ease and it will be composable.